# What data is sent from a client to a server in a federated learning setting?

Tags: machine-learning, differential-privacy, distributed-computing

So far, I thought federated learning works like this:

All clients have the same machine learning model (if not personalized). They have their unique data and then train this model (e.g., neural network) with their data. Then, they have a new matrix of neural network weights.

They then either share the new matrix completely with the server, or at least the changed matrix parameters.

However, in a recent [post](https://www.reddit.com/r/MLQuestions/comments/erskr7/how_computationally_efficient_or_inefficient_is/) of mine, a user said:

> it looks like you might also seem to think that final parameters are
>   the things communicated upstream in federated learning. This isn't the
>   case, it's gradient updates which go upstream.

I don't quite understand what the difference is - a neural network consists of one or several weight matrix/matrices, so this should be shared, not?